# How to make htaccess ignore part of url

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

We have this url: example.com/automobile/?id=1234 and for seo purposes need it to be like example.com/automobile/passenger/ferrari/?id=1234

we want the /passenger/ferrari/ to be opcional since that data is not relevant for our query and its dynamic.
So if a user goes to example.com/automobile/?id=1234 or to example.com/passenger/what/ever-is-written-here/?id=1234 goes to the the original url: example.com/automobile/?id=1234

We are working with wordpress and have this rules now:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I'm sorry, but it doesn't seem to work.
Maybe I can explain with an example:
Check this: 
[link](
http://www.casaesol.com/imovel/apartamento/t2-2-quartos/venda/usado/guia-albufeira-faro/?id=2730876)

If you change the url part of /apartamento/t2-2-quartos/venda/usado/guia-albufeira-faro/ it will take you to the same url. http://www.casaesol.com/imovel/?id=2730876

Or another example:
https://casa.sapo.pt/Apartamento-T1-Venda-Loures-Loures-Infantado-d4acc412-3146-4f8b-bc8f-820cf556f853.html

If you change the part of url: Apartamento-T1-Venda-Loures-Loures-Infantado to 
https://casa.sapo.pt/whateveryouwrite-d4acc412-3146-4f8b-bc8f-820cf556f853.html

It points to the same place

Answer (score 1):

To redirect

- /passenger/what/ever-is-written-here/?id=1234

to

- /automobile/?id=1234

put the following above your other rules :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /passenger/.+\?id=([0-9]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /automobile/?id=%1 [L,R,NE]
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast response, but the '/passenger/' is not a folder, and can have any other word on it. How can I make it accept any word instead?

Comment: In that case ,you can replace the Condition with this :

    `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(?:(?!automobile).+)\?id=([0-9]+) [NC]`

This accepts any chars except "/automobile/" before the query string

Comment: I'm sorry, but it doesn't seem to work.
Maybe I can explain with an example:

Comment: I just want to be able to write something in a specific position of the url that can be ignored but still be printed on the browser. In the examples above they can do it